# GWT DnD: Keep draggable within an AbsolutePanel

Tags: gwt, widget, drag-and-drop

I made a MultiSlider widget using the GWT and the gwt-dnd addon to rate texts. On the screenshot, you can see the slider button with value 50 dragged outside the slider bar. It can't be dropped outside the bar, but it can be dragged outside of it.

[alt text http://lt3.hogent.be/hendi_docs/stackoverflow/gwt-dnd-multislider.png](http://lt3.hogent.be/hendi_docs/stackoverflow/gwt-dnd-multislider.png)

Is there a way in GWT to always keep the slider buttons inside the slider bar?

EDIT:

The slider bar is an AbsolutePanel, and it is also the only droptarget for the slider buttons. The slider bar panel is also the boundary panel for the drop controller. Dropping outside of the bar panel is not possible, but dragging is.

Now what I really like to know is if it's possible to keep the mouse pointer on the bar panel. If a button is dragged out of it, it will remain on its old position when dropped (so that's OK). Is it possible to allow only vertical DRAGGING? Can the mouse position be set while dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `dragController.setConstrainWidgetToBoundaryPanel(true)`, and I think `dragController.setBehaviorConstrainedToBoundaryPanel(true)` does the same thing. For more information, check out the [javadoc for your version](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/downloads/list).

Comment: That keeps the sliders in the bar after they are dropped. I would like the slider buttons to stay within the bar while they are dragged. Can e.g. the mouse X position be set?

Comment: Sorry, I used the surrounding panel as boundary panel. Your solution works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is defined in AbstractDragController with this signature;
  void setBehaviorConstrainedToBoundaryPanel(boolean constrainedToBoundaryPanel);

The boundary panel (often passed in in the first parameter to the drag controller constructor) in this case should be an AbsolutePanel which wraps the slider.

It may also be helpful to visualize the absolute panel if things are not working as expected:
  absolutePanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "1px dashed red");